# How can i make my bot ask a statement, wait for the response of that statement

Tags: bots, slack-api, botkit

Is there any way i can ask my bot a question and make it wait for a response to that particular question so i could do some more things on that particular message?

Comment: Was the answer what you were looking for? Why don't you set it as the accepted answer or provide feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are examples in the botkit readme. copy pasting :

```
controller.hears(['question me'], 'message_received',function(bot,message) {

  // start a conversation to handle this response.
  bot.startConversation(message,function(err,convo) {

    convo.ask('How are you?',function(response,convo) {

      convo.say('Cool, you said: ' + response.text);
      convo.next();
    });
  })
})
```